# Creating a breakout panel for a Raspberry Pi GPIO lines

Tags: raspberry-pi, gpio, breakout

From the [elinux.org documentation](http://elinux.org/RPi_Low-level_peripherals#General_Purpose_Input.2FOutput_.28GPIO.29) for this GPIO, I have summarized the following information:

> The Raspberry Pi Model A+ and B+ boards, and the Pi 2 Model B, have a
>   40-pin 2.54 mm header marked J8, arranged as 2x20 pins. GPIO voltage
>   levels are 3.3 V and are not 5 V tolerant. There is no over-voltage
>   protection on the board - the intention is that people interested in
>   serious interfacing will use an external board with buffers, level
>   conversion and analog I/O rather than soldering directly onto the main
>   board.

The header looks like this:

[image]

What I would like to do is create a breakout panel that provides, primarily, easy to access and labelled jumper lead sockets for the GPIO lines from the header on the Pi board. I would like to add over-voltage protection for 3.3V, and also possibly an LED for each line to indicate it's high or low status.

I haven't been active in electronics for a long time, so I would like to know what the ideal socket type would be, as opposed to large and clumsy olden day "banana plugs", and then how to provide over-voltage protection. The sockets should be further spaced and much harder to incorrectly select than the fine spacing on a breadboard based breakout.

One of the first and simplest experiments with the Pi is powering an LED, with resistor, directly connected to a ground and output pin on the GPIO header. If possible, I would like to include such an LED for each GPIO line on my breakout panel, but can I do this without affecting the normal function of that line with whatever circuit it is actually used to communicate with.

Comment: 'ideal' depends on your situation. What would you want to connect to? For breadboard wires, 'wire cups' spaced 2.54 mm apart (in a single row) are ideal. But if you want to connect thick wires to a screw terminal you would need a quite different spacing.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen I think maybe wire cups will be a good choice. I can mount them on a pre-labelled PCB or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

You definitely don't want to have an LED pre-wired to every GPIO pin, since it would like interfere with future use of those pins.

Rather than try to build your own, which is going to be a lot of work, take a couple of weeks just to get boards made, and be costly  -- since making just a couple of PCB's is always expensive -- I suggest looking into solutions already available such as this one using a [cable connected to a breadboard](http://www.adafruit.com/products/914?gclid=CJWx0NLJhcgCFVKPfgodpNYDqg):

[image]

or this one [using a cape type board](http://www.adafruit.com/products/801?gclid=COSjh9HJhcgCFYqEfgodPGgMtQ), both made by Adafruit.

[image]

Comment: Adafruit have some very nice looking 'Cobblers', thanks for the reference. Not quite what I want, but may be useful in many other scenarios.

I guess I'll have to hack up a UI control that I can place anywhere on a screen to show me the states of all GPIO lines.